# Proving that a ball is open in Euclidean metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've come across an exercise in an analysis book that is presented as follows:

We define the function || $\cdot$ ||$_1$ : $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $||x||_1 := max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$.
The distance that belongs to  || $\cdot$ ||$_1$ is noted by $d_1$. The ball defined by this metric with center $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and radius $r>0$ is noted by $B_1(a;r)$.

The task is then to prove that for every $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and for every $r > 0$ the ball $B_1(a;r)$ is open in Euclidean metric space.

I've started like this:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be random, let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $p \in B_1(a;r)$. 
Then $d_1(p,a)< \epsilon$, and so $||p-a||_1<\epsilon$.
Take $\delta = \epsilon-d_1(p,a)$, so $\delta$ will be greater than 0.
Then we have $\forall x \in B_1(p,\delta)$ that $d(p,x)<\delta$.
It follows that $d(a,x) \leq d(a,p) + d(x,p) < d(a,p) + \delta = d(a,p)+ \epsilon - d_1(a,p)$.
I'm sure that I've come close to proving that the ball is open in Euclidean metric space, but I can't seem to think of the last step necessary.
Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in \mathbb R^2$ arbitrary and $r > 0$. Let $x \in B_1(a,r)$, then we have $\Vert x - a \Vert_1 < r$. Set $r_2 := \frac{r - \Vert x - a \Vert_1}{2}$ and let $y \in B_1(x, r_2)$. Then we have 
$$\Vert y - a \Vert_1 \leq \Vert y - x \Vert_1 + \Vert x - a \Vert_1 \leq \frac r 2 + \frac{\Vert x - a \Vert_1}{2} < r.$$
So we showed that $B_1(x, r_2) \subseteq B_1(a,r)$. Hence $B_1(a,r)$ is open.

Please consider that I haven't used anything else than the axioms of the metric. Because of that you can show, that every ball $B(a,r)$ in a metric space is open. That doesn't depend on the norm or the metric.